# Just to be sure, do copy softwares like HTTRACK download script files too?

Tags: backup

So I am pretty new to web-building and have completed building a website recently and about to put it online. Question is straight-forward, do these back-up softwares like HTTRACK  also download script files such as php and js-files etc. It may not be a bright question and I think that mostly the answer is no, but as a newbie I want to be sure.

Comment: What HTTRACK backs up is pretty much what you see, so, no PHP, and js only when its part of the page. Anything serverside, like php, and server side js like what node.js uses will not. Anything client side should.

Comment: so if it is a part of the page, it will download js. Noted. thanks.